# Need assistance reading the object returned by getRowId of MaterialReactTable

Tags: parsing, material-ui, react-table

I am using MaterialReactTable in my application and following the Row Selection Option as outlined at this link: https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/row-selection

The table is working fine and I am able to select the row I want and it returns the correct id but returns it in the format: rowSelection =  {63d19bebc764a5587a48683a: true}.  I am not familiar with this format.

I have tried everything I know but am unable to parse out the id from the object.

Please provide suggestion to parse out the id or suggest changes to make this solution work.

I have tried the other methods of row selection suggested on the page (useRef and '@tanstack/react-table') and could not get either to work so would like to stick to this method as I feel it is close.

Below is the code and options I am using with the MaterialReactTable

```
 return (
    <MaterialReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      enableRowSelection
      onRowSelectionChange={setRowSelection}
      enableMultiRowSelection={false}
      //getRowId={(row) => row?._id }
      getRowId={(originalRow) => originalRow._id}
      initialState={{ showColumnFilters: true,
        columnVisibility: 
        { _id: false } }} //hide columns listed to start }}
      manualFiltering
      manualPagination
      manualSorting
      muiToolbarAlertBannerProps={
        isError
          ? {
              color: 'error',
              children: 'Error loading data',
            }
          : undefined
      }
      muiTableBodyRowProps={({ row }) => ({
        //add onClick to row to select upon clicking anywhere in the row
        onClick: row.getToggleSelectedHandler(), 
        sx: { cursor: 'pointer' },
      })}
      onColumnFiltersChange={setColumnFilters}
      onGlobalFilterChange={setGlobalFilter}
      onPaginationChange={setPagination}
      onSortingChange={setSorting}
      rowCount={rowCount}
      state={{
        columnFilters,
        globalFilter,
        isLoading,
        pagination,
        showAlertBanner: isError,
        showProgressBars: isRefetching,
        sorting,
        rowSelection
      }}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of the response, rowSelection = {63d19bebc764a5587a48683a: true}, I had originally assumed a key: value pair with the id being the key.  My initial attempts to parse out the id as the key had failed.  After trying a number of different options, I was able to use the Object.keys() function as follows:

```
console.log(Object.keys(rowSelection));  //used to view the key(s) returned
setCurrentRoom(Object.keys(rowSelection));

This code converted the id to a string in an array as follows: currentRoom =  ['63d19bd9c764a5587a486836']
```